# Weird Bluetooth Behavior, difficulty reconnecting to paired device - Galaxy S II

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, bluetooth-audio, bluetooth-pairing

I had been having this weird behavior with my BT - Headset, that it works fine if I pair manually, but when I try to reconnect to a previously connected device, it would connect, and then just fail, and **I would need to unpair and repair manually every time**.

I have verified that this same headset **works as expected with other phones** - ranging from iPhone - Blackberry - Nokia Symbian S60. The device itself is over a year old, and this is when my previous device failed. However the fact that other phones are able to handle it, negates the possibility of this being purely due to age.

I tried to get Samsung Customer support to take a look at this, but they refused to see the problem.

Until recently I had just resigned myself to pairing it every time I want to use it, however recently, I seem to have discovered a pattern. If I disable the "Phone" Setting from bluetooth settings, this problem occurs. **However with both "Phone" and "Media" options enabled, it seems to work as good as new**!!

I also came across [Bluetooth Auto Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.myklos.btautoconnect&feature=search_result) which seems to be tackling a similar problem, but I don't think it is quite the same.

So basically my question is, is this a known/common issue with GSII? Is there a fix for it? My device is rooted if that helps.

If this is a purely software issue as I now suspect, will a new rom help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed when I flashed custom roms. It came with its own can of worms.. but still..

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issues with some headphones on my Galaxy Nexus, though it is only intermittent. While I do not have an actual solution, I have found that turning Bluetooth off and on again while the headphones are on is much quicker than navigating all those submenus, and does cause the headphones to reconnect.